# Регулярные выражения в PHP выборка из двух шаблонов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день имеются два шаблона поиска, они должны идти 1 к 1 т.е. первый элемент первого шаблона должен совпадать с первым элементом второго шаблона и т.д., но имеются подозрения что в одном из массивов могут не совпадать данные, как мне сделать чтобы можно было записать первую строку первого шаблона, и сразу же первую строку второго шаблона. Сейчас использую `preg_match_all`

```
// Получаем координаты.  

$pattern =  "/(?<=data-map_coords=\")\-?\d+\.\d+, \-?\d+\.\d+(?=\")/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $newString, $coord);

// Получаем города.
$pattern = "/(?<=>)[\w\s.]+(?=<\/a>)/ui";
preg_match_all($pattern, $newString, $cities);

// Собираем массив ключ значение из полученных данных.
$len = count($cities[0]);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    $coordinates = explode(',', $coord[0][$i]);
    $city = $cities[0][$i];
    $data[] = array(
        'country_id' => $key->id,
        'city_name' => $city,
        'latitude' => doubleval($coordinates[0]),
        'longitude' => doubleval($coordinates[1])
    );
}
```

Comment: Может быть покажите кодом то, что делаете сейчас?

Comment: Исправил текст, добавил код

Answer (score 1):

Задавая вопрос по регулярным выражениям приводите образец текста, который надо разбирать.

Чтобы два выражения следовали один за другим объедините их с помощью минимальной квантификации `.*?` . Раз соответствующие куски текста следуют один за другим, то это поможет. **Исключение**: если есть текст1, но нет текста2, или наоборот, то это не поможет.
В-целом это будет выглядеть так:

```
(regex1).*?(regex2)
```

Группы нужны, чтобы сохранить отдельные части совпадения.
Для того, чтобы текст строго соответствовал 1 к 1 нужно исключить возможность включения текст1 в совпадение, если для предыдущего текст1 не было парного текст2.

```
(regex1)(?:.(?!(?1)))*?(regex2)
```

Это не очень производительно, зато очень легко.
Для вашего конкретного случая:

```
((?<=data-map_coords=\")\-?\d+\.\d+, \-?\d+\.\d+(?=\"))(?:.(?!(?1)))*?((?<=>)[\w\s.]+(?=<\/a>))
```

Comment: Спасибо, но в том то и дело, что текста может не быть, хотя я не знаю почему такое получается, так как в самом файле текст есть везде, наверное шабло не срабатывает. `<>` а что это в php вроде неравно `!=`

Comment: @ElSalvadore Задавая вопрос по регулярным выражениям приводите образец текста, который надо разбирать.

Comment: Хорошо, текст просто очень большой.

Comment: @ElSalvadore не обязательно приводить текст целиком. Достаточно привести текст содержащий все возможные вариации размещения важных для регулярного выражения данных.